# Nuxt.js and srcDir option: Rendering url favicon 404 error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

After adding [srcDir option](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-srcdir) in a `nuxt.config.js` file, I've moved pages, components and layouts folders to src directory. Here is my configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  srcDir: 'src',

  head: {
    title: 'hello',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'test' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Now I'm getting the following error message:

```
nuxt:render Rendering url /favicon.ico +640ms
{ statusCode: 404,
  path: '/favicon.ico',
  message: 'This page could not be found' }
```

Removing `.nuxt` folder then rebuild the application doesn't help. What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess your favicon is in `static` directory, correct me if wrong. Did you move your `static` directory into `src`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful Yes, it is in static directory. Should I move static dir also? I'm planning to build a static website, is there anything else I need to move it to src folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your favicon is in `static` directory: you must move it into `src` with all your sources.

[The documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-srcdir) doesn't provide an exhaustive list of "should-be-moved" directories, but I guess other source directories like `assets` shoud be moved as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the documentation isn't clear enough. Do you recommend to move all the directories including plugins and store except something like dist test?

Comment: I recommend to look into the code source where the `srcDir` is used to be sure about the impacted directories. I will look into it if I can find some time, let me know if you do before I do ;)